# Replace letters by their rank, keeping punctuation intact

Tags: code-golf, string

The problem is simple. Given a string such as `Hello World!` the program would output `8-5-12-12-15 23-15-18-12-4-!`. Any delimiters will do, (please specify what they are though) I just chose to use space between words and dashes between characters.

The conversion is that all alphabetical characters will be converted to their numeric equivalent. i.e. `A=1,B=2,...,Z=26`. All other characters must be kept intact. Case insensitive.
Another example

```
Here's another example, I hope that this will illustrate my point! If it's unable, more specs will be given.
8-5-18-5-'-19 1-14-15-20-8-5-18 5-24-1-13-16-12-5-, 9 8-15-16-5 20-8-1-20 20-8-9-19 23-9-12-12 9-12-12-21-19-20-18-1-20-5 13-25 16-15-9-14-20-! 9-6 9-20-'-19 21-14-1-2-12-5-, 13-15-18-5 19-16-5-3-19 23-9-12-12 2-5 7-9-22-5-14-.
```

Note that there are no trailing or starting delimiters between characters.

Scoring will be based on the shortest amount of code. Any language is welcome.

As long as more answers are provided I will change the winner.
GLHF!

Comment: One test case does not constitute a specification.

Comment: @JanDvorak that would be acceptable as well. Just indicate which delimiters are being used.

Comment: What is an "alphabetical character"? Just `A-Za-z` with no accents? And is this really [tag:cryptography]?

Comment: @PeterTaylor alphabetical character is A-Za-z, case insensitive. It's a basic cypher.

Comment: @Taka it's not an encryption. It's an encoding. Lossy encoding, and inefficient.

Comment: Maybe encoding rather than cipher. [edit, Jan beat me to it]

Comment: @JanDvorak ok, should I change the tags?

Comment: @Taka yep. 'tis ain't cryptography any more than base64 is.

Comment: Where should the separators be inserted? From the examples seems that separators should occur between codes and other characters except space. So “a c/dc” becomes “1 3-/-4-2”? So space is the only exception?

Comment: @manatwork yes, that seems to be the case. Sorry I didn't mention that.

Comment: I think you accepted an answer too early. Others haven't had a chance to give it a shot.

Comment: @arshajii I said that as long as more answers are provided I'll change who the winner is. Is that the wrong way to do it? If so what should I do?

Comment: The examples may still not be enough comprehensive. As I understand, “abc_123” has to become “1-2-3-_-1-2-3”, right?

Comment: The disagreement in the comments on my answer also indicate that the spec is still ambiguous.

Comment: @mantawork yes that is right.

Comment: Furthermore, I would have been restricted the delimiters to single characters. Using “- -” as word separator currently complies with the rules, but voids the one clarified in [your earlier comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12253/replace-letters-by-their-rank-keeping-punctuation-intact/12262#comment23768_12253).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### GolfScript (<strike>24</strike> 22 chars)

```
{.32|96^:@`]@(26/!=n}%
```

is a hybrid of Howard's solution and my previous one:

```
{.223&65-.26/!{)`\}*;n}%
```

Since the spec states that I can use any delimiter, I've chosen to use newline.

[Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJIZWxsbywgd29ybGQhIgp7LjMyfDk2XjpAYF1AKDI2LyE9bn0l)

Comment: Nice abuse of the delimiter rule!

Comment: I'd like to upvote your solution - but you don't have a word delimiter, do you?

Comment: @Howard, I don't have a *different* word delimiter, but the spec is so vague that it doesn't seem to require one.

Comment: @PeterTaylor It does. Take e.g. `"Hello\nworld"` as input and you'll end up with three delimiters between words instead of one. (btw. my solution reduces to 23 chars if I'd take the same approach ;-) )

Comment: @Howard if you put a delimiter in the input to any of the programs it would look like it was more. Unless we want to clear for those, which isn't specified. This keeps it intact, technically.

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby 2.0, 41+1 characters

There, now it complies with the updated rules and makes prettier output.

```
gsub(/\w+/){$&.chars.map{|c|c.ord&31}*?-}
```

Run with `-p` switch:

```
ruby -p ord.rb <<< "ABC! Defghi, jklmnopqr stuvwxyz"
1-2-3! 4-5-6-7-8-9, 10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18 19-20-21-22-23-24-25-26
```

Comment: Nice one. But seems there should be no dashes around the spaces.

Comment: @manatwork it was submitted before I cleared that up. So it's cool, and is quite good.

Comment: @manatwork, @taka; fixed it anyways :)

Comment: @daniero do you know how to run this online? Also wish I could upvote this.

Comment: Nice answer. I *think* you can do `c.ord&31` and save 5 characters ;)

Comment: @Taka no, unfortunately I haven't found an online resource which supports the correct version of Ruby and lets you run it with the -p option.

Comment: Even greater. But still a glitch: now there are no separators neither around the unencoded characters.

Comment: @manatwork Yes I know. And actually I like it. The problem is not that accurately described, and the encoding is lossy no matter what, so I'll cut myself some slack; The key problem to be solved in the question is translating alphabetic characters to numbers, which the program does.

Comment: @daniero, I somehow agree. (You got my upvote anyway.) I was just curious whether more spectacular twists can be condensed in that code. (My first unposted try was also in `ruby`. About double of your code…)

Comment: @manatwork Thank you. Yes, I think separating and dealing with the non-alpha characters more precisely takes way more code. In codegolf I prefer shorter code and less accurate output; Dealing with special cases is not the golfing way. I first tried some more complicated stuff, but [this bug](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8023) and some other weird behavior made me call it off.

Answer (score 5):

## Perl: <s>42</s> 38 characters

```perl
s/\S(?=\S)/$&-/g;s/[a-z]/31&ord$&/ige
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.1$ perl -pe 's/\S(?=\S)/$&-/g;s/[a-z]/31&ord$&/ige' <<< "Here's another example, I hope that this will illustrate my point! If it's unable, more specs will be given."
8-5-18-5-'-19 1-14-15-20-8-5-18 5-24-1-13-16-12-5-, 9 8-15-16-5 20-8-1-20 20-8-9-19 23-9-12-12 9-12-12-21-19-20-18-1-20-5 13-25 16-15-9-14-20-! 9-6 9-20-'-19 21-14-1-2-12-5-, 13-15-18-5 19-16-5-3-19 23-9-12-12 2-5 7-9-22-5-14-.
```

Comment: You can shorten the replacement part of the second substitution to `31&ord$&`.

Comment: In the second substitution, `[a-z]` may be replaced by `\pL`, making the `i` flag unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you, @primo. Unicode character properties somehow didn't made their way into my regular expressions. As “alphabetical character is A-Za-z”, this will somehow violate the rules. But will keep it in mind and use it if the other answers will have more relaxed attitude on respecting the rules.

Answer (score 5):

#### GolfScript, <strike>37</strike> <strike>36</strike> 23 characters

The following version takes newline as delimiter (as Peter's solution):

```
{.32|96^:@`]@27,?0>=n}%
```

A version which interprets words and delimiters as in the examples given is 36 characters long:

```
' '/{'-'*{.32|96^:@`]@27,?0>=}%' '}%
```

(Strange enough my first version `` '-''- -'/' '{.32|96^:@`@0>@27<&if}% `` didn't work...)

Takes input on STDIN. The example can be [tested online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyJIZWxsbyB3b3JsZCEiCgonICcveyctJyp7LjMyfDk2XjpAYF1AMjcsPzA%2BPX0lJyAnfSUK&run=true):

```
> 'Hello world!'
8-5-12-12-15 23-15-18-12-4-!
```

Comment: Could you show how to run it. Using [golf online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/)

Answer (score 3):

### R - 134 characters

A bit too long to be really in competition but here we go:

```
s=sapply
l=letters
cat(s(strsplit(scan(,""),""),function(x)paste(s(tolower(x),function(y)ifelse(y%in%l,which(l==y),y)),collapse="-")))
```

Word delimiter is space, character delimiter is `-`.

Answer (score 2):

### Tcl, 82

```
lmap a [split [string tol $i] {}] {expr {[string is alpha $a]?[scan $a %c]-96:$a}}
```

Because you did not specify what you want, well, here an expression.
Input in `i`, result of the expression is the result.

Example:

```
% set i "Hello World!"
Hello World!
% lmap a [split [string tol $i] {}] {expr {[string is alpha $a]?[scan $a %c]-96:$a}}
8 5 12 12 15 { } 23 15 18 12 4 !
```

Word delimiter is `{ }`, character delimiter is

Answer (score 2):

### Python - 47 <del>63</del>

This assumes you've assigned the string to the variable `s`.

47 uses a flagrant abuse of the rules and says that `[` is the delimiter for the start of the original string, `]` marks the end of the original string, `,` marks the different characters and unchanged characters are captured in quotes.

```
str([(x,ord(x)-64)[x.isalpha()] for x in s.upper()])
```

Alternatively, 62 squeezes a line from below (although `'A'<=x<='Z'` is just as long and works just as well.:

```
'-'.join([str((x,ord(x)-64)[x.isalpha()]) for x in s.upper()])
```

63:

```
'-'.join([str((x,ord(x)-64)[64<ord(x)<91]) for x in s.upper()])
```

And the sample output:

```
>>> s = "Hello World!"
>>> '-'.join([str((x,ord(x)-64)[64<ord(x)<91]) for x in s.upper()])
'8-5-12-12-15- -23-15-18-12-4-!'
```

Comment: I'm not sure I would consider these programs, as they don't read any input from `stdin`, nor do they write any output to `stdout`. A 52 byte program, abusing the newline delimeter as @PeterTaylor does: `for x in raw_input():print(x,ord(x)&31)[x.isalpha()]`

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript, <del>81</del> 74**

<del>`""+[].map.call(prompt(),function(c){a=c.charCodeAt(0);return a>65&&a<123?a&31:c})`</del>

With the input taken from a variable
`""+[].map.call(s,function(c){a=c.charCodeAt(0);return a>65&&a<123?a&31:c})`

Output from the string you chose

> 8,5,18,5,',19, ,1,14,15,20,8,5,18, ,5,24,1,13,16,12,5,,, ,9, ,8,15,16,5, ,20,8,1,20, ,20,8,9,19, ,23,9,12,12, ,9,12,12,21,19,20,18,1,20,5, ,13,25, ,16,15,9,14,20,!, ,9,6, ,9,20,',19, ,21,14,1,2,12,5,,, ,13,15,18,5, ,19,16,5,3,19, ,23,9,12,12, ,2,5, ,7,9,22,5,14,.

```
          |  Word  |  Char  |
Delimiters|  , ,   |    ,   |
```

Comment: “All other characters must be kept intact.” – You also encoded the punctuations.

Comment: @manatwork Oops, Thanks! i have missed that part, fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica 68

Commas used as separators.

```
If[64 < # < 97, # - 64, FromCharacterCode@#] & /@ ToCharacterCode@ToUpperCase@i
```

**Example**

```
i="To be, or not to be,--that is the question:-- Whether 'tis nobler in
the mind to suffer The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune Or to
take arms against a sea of troubles, And by opposing end them?";

If[64 < # < 97, # - 64, FromCharacterCode@#] & /@ ToCharacterCode@ToUpperCase@i
```

> {20, 15, " ", 2, 5, ",", " ", 15, 18, " ", 14, 15, 20, " ", 20, 15, "
> ", 2, 5, ",", "-", "-", 20, 8, 1, 20, " ", 9, 19, " ", 20, 8, 5, " ",
> 17, 21, 5, 19, 20, 9, 15, 14, ":", "-", "-", " ", 23, 8, 5, 20, 8, 5,
> 18, " ", "'", 20, 9, 19, " ", 14, 15, 2, 12, 5, 18, " ", 9, 14, " ",
> 20, 8, 5, " ", 13, 9, 14, 4, " ", 20, 15, " ", 19, 21, 6, 6, 5, 18, "
> ", 20, 8, 5, " ", 19, 12, 9, 14, 7, 19, " ", 1, 14, 4, " ", 1, 18,
> 18, 15, 23, 19, " ", 15, 6, " ", 15, 21, 20, 18, 1, 7, 5, 15, 21, 19,
> " ", 6, 15, 18, 20, 21, 14, 5, " ", 15, 18, " ", 20, 15, " ", 20, 1,
> 11, 5, " ", 1, 18, 13, 19, " ", 1, 7, 1, 9, 14, 19, 20, " ", 1, " ",
> 19, 5, 1, " ", 15, 6, " ", 20, 18, 15, 21, 2, 12, 5, 19, ",", " ", 1,
> 14, 4, " ", 2, 25, " ", 15, 16, 16, 15, 19, 9, 14, 7, " ", 5, 14, 4,
> " ", 20, 8, 5, 13, "?"}

Answer (score 2):

### C# - 137 Characters

This code assumes the string to convert is the **s** variable

```
Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(s.ToUpper(),@"[A-Z]",m=>(((int)m.Value[0])-64).ToString()+'-'),@"[^\w\s-]",m=>m.Value+'-').Replace("- "," ");
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
26R;`,@ØẠyK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYy9DcIwGAVXeVQ0EQUFDQ0lER0T4KAHNvKf7C@AJ2AFSuagzSRMYoxEcdfdXWhtqXW52q8P3WZ6ft6vsqvTo9YtE@cZygfRTOBduWjZoYcOkRCtpMlk3Iy1aIxZkhLCFcRgvMzQn2CkPUavhl/qQiJy5PEfDcTZXOkXXw)

Uses space as a delimiter.

### How it works

```
26R;`,@ØẠyK - Main link. Takes a string s on the left
26R         - Yield [1, 2, ..., 26] 
   ;`       - Concatenate it to itself; [1, 2, ..., 26, 1, 2, ..., 26]
       ØẠ   - Yield "ABC...XYZabc...xyz"
     ,@     - Pair; [["A", "B", ..., "Z", "a", ..., "z"], [1, 2, ..., 26, 1, ..., 26]]
         y  - Transliterate s according to the mapping above
          K - Join by spaces
```

Comment: Shouldn't the delimiter _only_ be included after letters?

Comment: @Shaggy Judging from "I just chose to use space between words and dashes between characters." in the question, and from Peter Taylor's [7 year old answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12259/66833), I think its acceptable to use the same delimiter between each of the characters

Comment: Ah, yes, I see how that could be abused now :)

Answer (score 1):

## Q, 53

```
{1_ssr[-3!(`$'x)^`$(.Q.a!($)1+(!)26)@(_)x;"``";"  "]}
```

Backtick Delimited

```
q){1_ssr[-3!(`$'x)^`$(.Q.a!($)1+(!)26)@(_)x;"``";"  "]}"Here's another example, I hope that this will illustrate my point! If it's unable, more specs will be given."
"8`5`18`5`'`19  1`14`15`20`8`5`18  5`24`1`13`16`12`5`,  9  8`15`16`5  20`8`1`20  20`8`9`19  23`9`12`12  9`12`12`21`19`20`18`1`20`5  13`25  16`15`9`14`20`!  9`6  9`20`'`19  21`14`1`2`12`5`,  13`15`18`5  19`16`5`3`19  23`9`12`12  2`5  7`9`22`5`14`."
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0 [`-S`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¬®r\lÈc uH
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&flags=LVM&code=rK5yXGzIYyB1SA&input=IkhlcmUncyBhbm90aGVyIGV4YW1wbGUsIEkgaG9wZSB0aGF0IHRoaXMgd2lsbCBpbGx1c3RyYXRlIG15IHBvaW50ISBJZiBpdCdzIHVuYWJsZSwgbW9yZSBzcGVjcyB3aWxsIGJlIGdpdmVuLiI)

```
¬®r\lÈc uH     :Implicit input of string
¬              :Split
 ®             :Map
  r            :  Replace
   \l          :  /[A-Z]/gi
     È         :  Pass each match through a function
      c        :    Character code
        u      :    Modulo
         H     :    32
```